# Static folder v/s browser folder

Tags: angular, angular-universal

When using `Angular universal` to build an Angular project, 3 folders are generated in the `dist` folder.

- server
- static
- browser

The `server` folder is used for pre-rendering on server. However, the `static` and `browser` folders are used to deploy the website on a static hosting.

What is the difference between `static` and `browser` folders? And which one is better to deploy?

**EDIT 1:**
I recognized that both `static` and `browser` folders when deployed have the same content but structured differently.

- In static version: an index.html and some files (js, css, ...) in the root folder, in addition, each component has its own folder containing an index.html corresponding to the component.
- In browser version: an index.html and some files (js, css, ...) in the root folder with no folders corresponding to the components (their templates are embedded in the root folder files).

Below is `Angular.json` file content:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myapp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "myapp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "myapp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "myapp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "myapp"
}
```

Comment: Can you show you `angular.json` file? I'm not sure where the `static` folder comes from. Unless it's for assets, in which case you need to deploy both

Comment: @David I added `angular.json` file and additional information

Comment: My guess is that you are either using pre-rendering (and so you have one folder for each possible route) or that you are saving generated html after rendering a route. Which command are you using to compile and run ssr?

Comment: @David I first did `ng add @ng-toolkit/universal` and the command I use is `npm run build:prerender`. Note that both folders generate the same content but as I said structured differently. If you want, create a new angular app, add couple of components, run `ng add @ng-toolkit/universal` and `npm run build:prerender` so you see what I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

You need to deploy at least the `browser` folder, which will always be used. Deploy the `static` folder for your static routes if you want fast loading for these pages, and deploy the `server` folder if your hosting server allows `nodejs` to run and if you want to do dynamic rendering for dynamic routes (for fast loading and SEO  friendly pages).

**Explanation**

When using angular universal you have to differentiate dynamic rendering and pre-rendering.

**Dynamic rendering**

Whenever you access a page, angular universal will render the page (with nodejs, using the server bundles from the `server` directory), send the generated content back to the client (with components html already displayed, inlined CSS). After the page is loaded, the JS from the client angular app will take over, using the files from the `browser` folder (so the styles and the js files)

**Pre-rendering**

With pre-rendering, before deploy, a script will parse all of the static routes that you have defined in your routing (`/contact`, `/about`,...), perform rendering of these routes, and save the resulting html in the `static` folder, with one `index.html` file for each folder (where a folder corresponds to a route). So before you even access your website, you already have the correct html already generated.

When you access the `contact` route for instance, the `dist/static/contact/index.html` file will be returned. But, as with dynamic rendering, once the page is loaded, you will still have the angular JS app from the `browser` folder that will take over. You do not need nodejs if you only use prerendering.

You can probably deploy all 3 folders. The `browser` one will always be needed, and you can use the `static` folder for static routes and have `nodejs` use the `server` folder to render pages for dynamic routes

See more info on pre-rendering [here](https://medium.com/@maciejtreder/prerender-angular-application-be-seo-ae1183c621cb)